# delphi DBGrid set focus on current cell

Tags: delphi, focus, dbgrid

I have a dbgrid. I want to set a focus on the current **CELL** when i get error on `datachanged` event in my DataSource.

My code in the `OndataChanged` event is :

```
if (Field.Text = '') then
begin                   

        Application.MessageBox('ERROR','',MB_ICONWARNING);
        Field.Tag:= Field.DataSet.RecNo;
        Abort;
end
```

How  i can do that?

Comment: a)  Is the datachanged event being triggered by the user doing in-place editing in the grid?  b)  What do you mean by "current" cell - the cell which was focused immediately before you get the error or what?

Comment: a) there are an event `OnDataChanged` in my datasource...
b) the current cell : is the cell when i put a wrong data

Comment: b) example : when i click on the next cell with mouse .. i get error : the old cell can not be some format..

Comment: i'm in delphi 5.. yes it return to Cell was editing.. but i can in next step to click another cell ..

Comment: Needs an MCVE..

Comment: Well, yes. Of course you can then click another cell. What other behavior would you expect? (You can avoid all of these difficulties if you stop trying to use a DBGrid as a data entry tool, and instead create a form to edit data. You can also stop fighting so hard to do things in the DBGrid if you use the field's properties correctly; setting the field's `Required` property to true will allow Delphi to handle this for you automatically.)

Comment: all field in my case are added at runtime.. I have  tow fields for **case 1** or 4 fields in **case 2** ... How can set `Required` property in this case?

Comment: "How can set Required ...?" `DataSet.FieldByName('SomeField').Required := True`

Answer (score 1):

The code below shows how to

- Install a global exception handler
- Focus a given cell in a DBGrid, e.g. the one which was current when an exception occurred.
  See `FocusGridCell`
- Set a TField's Required property to True, which is what Ken White suggested you do.

As you can see, TForm1's `OnException` saves the current grid row and column into
the variables ERow and ECol so you can return to them later.

`FocusGridCell` allows you to return focus to the grid cell with the saved
ERow and ECol values after focus has been pulled away from the grid, e.g. by the
`Application.MessageBox` in your OnDataChange handler.

Hopefully that should be all you need to do what you want to do.

Btw, it's generally a *bad* idea to use pop-up messages to display stuff in
TDataSet event handlers: it's better to post yourself a custom message to the app's message queue and to do the pop-up in the custom message's handler, so that the pop-up will happen **after** the dataset event has completed.

Code:

```
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    [...]
  protected
    ERow,
    ECol : Integer;
    procedure OnException(Sender : TObject; E : Exception);
    procedure FocusGridCell(ACol, ARow: Integer);
  public
  end;

[...]

type
 TMyDBGrid = class(TDBGrid);

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ERow := -1;
  ECol := -1;
  Application.OnException := OnException;
end;

procedure TForm1.OnException(Sender: TObject; E: Exception);
begin
  ERow := TMyDBGrid(DBGrid1).Row;
  ECol := TMyDBGrid(DBGrid1).Col;
  //  the following shows a non-intrusive way to display status info without
  //  interfering with what's focused on the form, etc
  Caption := Format('Row: %d, Col: %d', [ERow, ECol]);
end;

procedure TForm1.FocusGridCell(ACol, ARow : Integer);
begin
  //  Unless the grid's dgAlwaysShowSelection  is True, the following
  //  call to DBGrid1.SetFocus is necessary, otherwise
  //  the call to SetFocus has no visible effect. 
  if not (dgAlwaysShowSelection in DBGrid1.Options) then
    DBGrid1.SetFocus;
  TMyDBGrid(DBGrid1).FocusCell(ACol, ARow, True);
end;
```

Comment: i get  `TMyDBGrid(DBGrid1).FocusCell(ACol, ARow, True); `undeclared identifier FocusCell

Comment: @userPro: Which Delphi version are you using?

Comment: "undeclared identifier FocusCell"  Make sure your unit USES Grids as well as DBGrids.  It should do automatically.  `FocusCell` is a protected-scope method of TCustomGrid and the `TMyDBGrid` declaration in my code should allow the compiler access to it in your unit.

Comment: I just checked and my code compiles on versions of Delphi from 7 to Delphi Seattle,  So if you are getting the error you say, it is due to an error in your unit's code.  Try creating a new project with your grid, dataset and datasource and only the code in my answer.

Comment: Delphi 5 won't make any difference whatsoever.  If you are still getting the "undeclared identifier" error, do what I said about creating a test project.  Otherwise, I don't think I can help you any more.